Unable to push data into a nested BSON object in Mongodb using pymongo
def insertDataComments(self, company_profile_id, thread_id, commenter, comment_text):
        DATABASE = "foretagsforum"
        db = client[DATABASE]
        collection = db.companies

        try:
            result = collection.update_one(
                {"_id": company_profile_id, "threads._id": thread_id},
                {"$push": {"threads.$.comments": {"commenter": commenter, "comment_text": comment_text}}}
            )
            return {"success": True, "matched_count": result.matched_count, "modified_count": result.modified_count}
        except OperationFailure as e:
            return {"error": f"Something went wrong: {e}"}
        finally:
            client.close()
    
    def fetchUserThreads(self,username,items:int=1): 
        DATABASE = "threads-relations"
        db = client[DATABASE]
        thread = db.relations
        try:    
            user_threads = thread.find({"username":username}).limit(items)
            threads_list = list(user_threads)
            return threads_list
        
        except OperationFailure as e:
            return {"Something went wrong":str(e)}
        
        finally:
            client.close()

So for some reason I am unable to push data into my nested bson object, for reference this is how the data is supposed to look like for example:
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "667f35a82435e055b88cdec4"
    },
    "company_name": "telenor-sverige-aktiebolag",
    "org_number": "556421-0309",
    "company_info": [],
    "threads": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "667f35e141b617793ba93d72"
            },
            "username": "Kalle",
            "thread_text": "This is the end of the long string.",
            "tags": [
                "string",
                "long",
                "word",
                "repetit",
                "repeat"
            ],
            "timestamp": {
                "$date": {
                    "$numberLong": "1719612897633"
                }
            },
            "category": "jobb",
            "comments": []
        }
    ]
}

What am I missing, I've tried googling around for solutions and nesting bson objects in this was seems very rare, essentially I am trying to push data within data within data.
This is the the result that I keep getting in the terminal:
{'success': True, 'matched_count': 0, 'modified_count': 0}
It seems to be able to find the correct id's but not updating said data

What does "unable" mean? Are you getting an error, data not getting saved, something crashing?
